# cross-filtering with different chart encodings via `hconcat` and `layer`

Tags: vega-lite

I was trying to adapt the [cross-filter example from the gallary](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_layered_crossfilter.html) to have an additional chart that is not a numeric value, e.g., `origin` from the [flights data set in the same example](https://vega.github.io/editor/data/flights-2k.json). However, the selections became rather strange after I moved the `transform` into the `hconcat` layer---opening a new chart instead of updating in place. I also wasn't sure how the selections composed across the charts now that there is another level of composition (`hconcat` in additional to `repeat` layering).

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVICAM2FksEfgCYA1lJnylxttuSY0oHEm0Q4Hg5h+6KqBIAC+EUqY2kiyEM6uaADaoFBIglAMgmpBGGw6EAAUIQwIlCFwAJSKIEgQ+pg0CH5hALpK2nA4cGr+UGyCpfKoSSo0EOqyUH5KynDZAJ41jc0grWFKEN1Q-jD9U70joL6CcFCNcv5M2gwQMP6YC936NLKB2sTpNXBTbMqvZHqIxAAA81pEQMhtDZ9ExvN9fv9ZGR-GDNCBjDR5sp9C4aLRHCBHs90C4kV8NiAluikGQyJ0KKF0P0GG9lk9cgBHBixRrqRqkcJKfqCFz+T6DXIAYmUsvCkVAizg2mSx3mZwuw1A11u93RxNyr3eEoR-SRgOSoPBlKhMPQcJVSh+ZoBqP8mOx-k63UOIBFQyFICYr38yBBwbiaCsAAZKQb9NzeXQ1DRBZTqaBafS+Ey-fk2VEOQmeW9kwKWsKBmL0RKGNLZTiIm0NqBorF4i4EKqMTRBO9-CcNexhkGbnd5e1Id47UH4U7Ea70WjQB7BDj0d6eu5mQMA5SI6GkOHXkCY3Gi+hE6X+amK1T-FmGTl9CyC0SLyAr3yU2mIuswkAA)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the main issue is that interval selections don't work on non-quantitative axes. You should try using a single or multi selection for this case.

Comment: Thanks, Jake, for the comment! Though I think the selection is actually working (if I select the airtports bar charts the other charts are updating). Also if I change the selection mechanism for the selection, something gets broken and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to ping Arvind for an answer here:

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVICAM2FksEfgCYA1lJnylxttuSY0oHEm0Q4Hg5h+6KqBIAC+EUqY2kiyEM6uaADaoFBIglAMgmpBGGw6EAAUIQwIlCFwAJSKIEgQ+pg0CH5hALpKMFByae6oKSDacDhwav5dgqXyfSo0EOqyUH5KynDZAJ41jc0grWFKEMNQ-utw2smgvoJwUI1y-kzaDBAw-phrw-o0soHaxOk1cAWbGUXzI9WmAA8dpEQMhtDZ9ExvACgSDZGR-FDNCBjDRVsp-INhqN0ONJuElEwvv5kBCqXE0FYAAx7EBvD7oACODFijXUjVIFJAG2xSDIZEGFFCpPy30271y3N5dDUNEFrPGLn8fwmuQAxMpDeFIqBorF4i4EOccTRBD9-JdrrcpiAHk8XhF2rDvAj0EizkpAV00RjsVjQLj8YShiNeiAyQh5Kz6TSkHSvuDmaz2Yqed8VQKWkoRaAxRK+NL47L3FEFfolfn+WqWp6TSATmc+hdVk72FNQG7nq86+gEFlGijg6DwUkQFDdqy4b7XcjA6jQZj-JHBAT0C4aLRHGyRyAXGj-qyS7VxZKcvougw5bWOSAG3zVeqlJrO6AdQx9YaBIRHspoxHECRWl2Np2qcDo9jcfaIo8Q6ekoS6IquIBBsCG5hlueI7vo+6HvKL5nl8F7Fv4Za3pWD5PseL5vgWzZCt+2rpP++hzHAqxMLqxptEJQA)

The error I had was that the repeat was outside of the spec, but it should have been inside the `hconcat` spec. Also, minor correct: interval selections do work on nominal axes.